# Constant flow of SMB packets

Tags: networking, network-printer, smb

My Windows 8 computer (192.168.1.105) is constantly trying to communicate to my Raspberry LAN SMB server (192.168.1.150)(which has a printer plugged in). And I'm seeing the following block of packets being transferred every 2 or 3 seconds.

[image: Wireshark table]

If I go to Windows resource monitor there's constant network activity by the 'system' process (don't know what exactly) to the SMB server.

Do you have any idea what it is?